# How does an injected python interpreter become aware and has access to the process it was injected into?

Tags: python-3.x, readprocessmemory

I've been testing pymem module. If the following code could be called testing:

```
from pymem import Pymem
import os
import subprocess

# launching notepad as subprocess
notepad_process = subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe'])

# attaching pymem to the launched notepad process
pm = Pymem('notepad.exe')

# injecting python interpreter
pm.inject_python_interpreter()

# defining path to the textfile
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'pymem_injection.txt')
print(filepath)
# fixing path string
filepath = filepath.replace("\\", "\\\\")
print(filepath)

# payload
# notepad.exe will have an injected interpreter that will execute the following code
shellcode = """
f = open("{}", "w+")
f.write("pymem injection using the pymem module")
f.close()
""".format(filepath)

# executing the payload
pm.inject_python_shellcode(shellcode)

# closing the notepad process
notepad_process.kill()
```

I do not understand what has to be done next, since the interpreter and notepad are pretty much unaware of each other's existence. For example how can I write text to notepad using the injected interpreter?